# NHibernate mapping an IDictionary problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I have an NHibernate mapping issue which I could use help with - the documentation & samples seem very unclear to me.

I have one class which contains a dictionary of another classs.  I'm unsure of the correct mapping and everything I've tried either fails to map, or gets a NHibernate exception on reading data.

The 2 classes are:

```
public class SnippetConfigParam
{
    public virtual int          SnippetValueKey { get; set; }
    public virtual string       ParamName { get; set; }
    public virtual string       Value{ get; set; }
}

public  class SnippetConfig
{
    public virtual int          SnippetKey { get; set; }


    public virtual ESnippetType Type{ get; set; }
    public virtual string       Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IDictionary<string, SnippetConfigParam> Params { get; set; }


    public virtual string       Description{ get; set; }


    public virtual VendorPage   Page{ get; set; }
}
```

My last mapping attempt was

```
<map name="Params"  table="SnippetConfigValue" lazy="false">
    <key column="SnippetConfigKey" />
    <index column="SnippetValueKey"  type="Int32"/>    
    <composite-element class ="SnippetConfigParam">
        <property name="ParamName"  />
        <property name="Value" />
    </composite-element>      
</map>
```

Which results in:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

So I'm clearly not understanding something.  The database tables are:

```
Create Table SnippetConfig
    SnippetKey  int not null, 
    ...
    PrimaryKey( 'SnippetKey' )

  Create Table SnippetConfigValue
    SnippetValueKey  int  not null,
    ...
    PrimaryKey( 'SnippetValueKey' ),
    Key  'fk' ( 'SnippetConfigKey' ),
    Constraint 'fk' foreign key ('SnippetConfigKey' ) references 'SnippetConfig' ('SnippetKey' )...
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping dictionary in NHibernate could be a bit tricky. See the detail description here: [Ayende's post about `<map>`](http://ayende.com/blog/4045/nhibernate-mapping-map). 
The key to understand it is in the mapping of the `TKey` and `TValue` (`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`)

- TKey is represented by `<index>` element
- TValue could be element, composite-element, one-to-many

Because your `TKey` is **string**:

```
public virtual IDictionary<string, SnippetConfigParam> Params { get; set; }
```

The mapping representing it cannot be the **int**

```
<index column="SnippetValueKey"  type="Int32"/>
```

Change the *Params* proeprty to be `IDictionary<int, SnippetConfigParam>` and it should work.

*NOTE: If you want the property SnippetValueKey of the class SnippetConfigParam to be filled extend the component*

```
<composite-element class ="SnippetConfigParam">
    <property name="SnippetValueKey" formula="SnippetValueKey " 
              insert="false" update="false" />
    <property name="ParamName"  />
    <property name="Value" />
</composite-element>
```

Comment: Beatutifully clarified Radim.  I do want the IDictionary to be a string as I want to access the params by name.  So I changed the index to   <index column="ParamName"  type="string" />. Type seems to be mandatory, not reflected.  I'm note sure what you mean by the filling of SnippetValueKey - I'll need teh key as a native primary key, but don't actually care about it.  I'll check out the formula & insert & update pars to fathom what the effect are.  Thanks again.

Comment: My note was to the fact, that your C# class `SnippetConfigParam` has property `SnippetValueKey`. This won't be filled by NHibernate unless you add the mapping with *formula* and *insert/update false*...otherwise it will be `0` all the time. Just a note;)